# Input data does not get stored in database, but no error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to get a user's comment and store in the database table column 1 and display the entered comment in different table. The code works fine with no errors, but the comment does not get stored in the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action=''>
    <input type="text" name='Comment'/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "escalation";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) $Comment = isset($_POST['Comment']) ? $_POST['Comment'] : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO css(Dis_Cmt)VALUES('$Comment')";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

if ($res) {
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='Uploadphp.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try,
$sql="INSERT INTO css(Dis_Cmt)VALUES('".$Comment."')";

Comment: @user1544541 That won't make any difference

Comment: You really want to use a prepared statement for that `INSERT`. Did you check `error.log` for messages? Is `$Comment` getting a valid value?

Comment: $conn->connect_errno (not error) use connect_error to display the message, see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: don't put this code into any server. you may destroy it. your code is prone to SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

try this.Notice the opening and closing bracket.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method='post' action=''>
        <input type="text" name='Comment'/>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>

<?php 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "escalation";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
            $Comment=isset($_POST['Comment']) ?$_POST['Comment']:'';


            $sql="INSERT INTO css(Dis_Cmt)VALUES('$Comment')";
            $res=$conn->query($sql);


              if($res){
                echo "Successful";
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "<a href='Uploadphp.php'>Back to main page</a>";
             }else {
               echo "ERROR";
             }
        }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Another info and a sort of advice though it does not concern to your question is please use prepared statement that will help prevent sql injection.
You can read php manual about mysqli prepared statement [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) .
You might also want to check PDO prepared statement [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).
You might also want to check this [this](https://github.com/jameshwartlopez/bosphp/blob/1b43ad8785aac71ff8b19d653be5d32c5367dc8b/framework/DB.php) full helper class for your crud operation that i personally created.That also uses PDO prepared statement.

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Yes, he must need to add brackets for starting and ending block.

Comment: side note: if the database connection isn't used for something else, too, I think the script should do the following: a) check isset(Submit) b) if yes:if(!isset(Comment) || notFeasible(Comment)) -> error c) establish database connection d) run query.

Comment: and the code is still prone to [sql injections](http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection).

Comment: I tried these codes as well. Still i don't get any errors. But the inserted value doesn't get stored in my Database table. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type="text" name='Comment'/>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
$server="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="escalation";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $Comment=isset($_POST['Comment']) ?$_POST['Comment']:'';

    $sql="INSERT INTO css(Dis_Cmt)VALUES('$Comment')";
    $res=$conn->query($sql);

    if($res){
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='Uploadphp.php'>Back to main page</a>";
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. No error message @devpro.. But the value doesn't get stored in my database.

Comment: alright did you checked your db structure? check data type of comments column.. its working fine..

Comment: check two things, db structure specially comments column and than check db connection or you can run your query manually in db

Comment: @Sugs, for checking db structure run this query in your db INSERT INTO css(Dis_Cmt)VALUES('test value'); if insert properly that means structure is fine

Comment: Ok. It works now with a new database. But i want this comment field inside a table row where user uploads a csv file and it gets displayed in a page. I want this comment field in the each uploaded raw to add a comment. But this code doesnt work there, PLs help

Comment: Ya I tried that too @devpro. Code works fine when i tried creating a new database. But I want this comment field inside a php table where the table displays the database contents to users. And I want the users to add a comment in each raw. Pls help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98074/discussion-between-devpro-and-sugs).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the $_POST is giving the output you want. If yes ,then try the mysql command on the commandline and see if it shows any error ... Your command should work, i tried it in my commandline, it worked. 
Either you havent set the correct data types and lengths of values in the database table or try this:

A safe command which always works is

```
"INSERT INTO `css`(`Dis_Cmt`)VALUES('.$Comment.')"
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

should be

```
(!$conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a echo before the INSERT. If its show up, the problem maybe the
   query or the table field;
2. Insert any value in css table using the
   phpmyadmin for testing;
3. Use prepared statement to avoid sql
   injection. Below, a example.

> ```
> $Comment = $_POST['Comment'];
> $sql = "INSERT INTO css (Dis_Cmt) VALUES (?)";
> $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
> $statement->bind_param('s', $Comment);
> if($statement){
>         echo "Successful";
>         echo "<BR>";
>         echo "<a href='Uploadphp.php'>Back to main page</a>";
>     }
>     else {
>         echo "ERROR";
>     }
> $statement->close();
> ```

Good luck!